# Multiple bones stay at the same place when I move in the timeline

Tags: animation, bones, timeline

Multiple bones stay at the same place when I move in the timeline.

enter link description here

Here is a video wwhere I show the problem a bit more.
[Blender problems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHi_V3hHKTk)

Here is the .blend file.

[image]

Comment: You have to keyframe the rotation too.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I hope it will fix it.